# Mongodb query doesn't work

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my image sharing application you can upload images and create albums. When you delete an image from the site it shall also be deleted in the albums (the ones that has got the image in it).

Below is the route for deleting an image, and what I really need help with is why the code for deleting the images (imageName and imageId) in the albums below doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

**The models:**

```
var AlbumSchema = new Schema({
      title             : String,
      imageName         : [String],
      imageId           : [String]
});

modelObject.AlbumSchema = AlbumSchema;
modelObject.Album = mongoose.model('Album', AlbumSchema);
```

-

```
var BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    size : Number,
    type : String,
    author : ObjectId,
    title   : String
});

modelObject.Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
modelObject.BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPostSchema);
```

**The part that doesn't work in the code below is the following:**

```
albums[i].imageName.remove(j);
albums[i].imageId.remove(j);                            
albums[i].save(function (err){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // do something
    }
});
```

**Full code:**

```
 app.get('/blog/delete/:id', function(req, res){

    model.BlogPost.findById(req.params.id, function (err, blog){

        var theImage = blog.name;

        var query = albumModel.Album.find( { imageName:theImage } )
        query.exec(function (err, albums) {

            if (!albums) {

                blog.remove(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    // do something
                });

                res.redirect('/blogs');

            }

            else {
                for (var i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j< albums[i].imageName.length; j++){

                        if (theImage == albums[i].imageName[j]){

                            albums[i].imageName.remove(j);
                            albums[i].imageId.remove(j);                            
                            albums[i].save(function (err){
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    // do something
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            blog.remove(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                // do something
            });

            res.redirect('/blogs');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript arrays don't have a `remove` method so I would expect your code may be crashing.  You should be using code like `albums[i].imageName.splice(j, 1);` instead.